# Azure DevOps Service has been imported database successful But error 404 NotFound can't access to link

Tags: azure-devops

I have migrated import database from TFS to Azure DevOps Service.I'm follow step by the instruction Guides of migration,The process migrate has been completed, please see the reference of screenshot [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8Ppm.png)

But after The tools has generated the link for tracking the status of importing,I can't access to it and The Azure dev returned response error 404 NotFound.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFM4a.png)

Please help to investigate this issue? and Anything suggestion for fix it.

Thank you

Comment: Hi, which migration method are you using (Dry run or Production run)? You could try to remove  the previous run and start `dry run` again.  You could check the `dataMigrationTool.log` on your local machine . The log may contain the cause of the error

Comment: I have ran with option Dryrun and Do you have any suggestion about how to remove previous run? I finding the command for deleting but it's not found.

Comment: The Product of the `Dry run` is an organizaiton. From your screenshot, it seems that the organization hasn't been created successfully. You may try to directly repeate the dry run steps. If the issue still exists, could you share some dataMigrationTool.log?